# ImageJ Synchronize Windows

Tags: windows, macros, imagej, synchronize

I was wondering if it was possible to set the parameters of Synchronize Windows from a macro in ImageJ.

```
// This will open the Synchronize Windows Function
run("Synchronize Windows");
```

My best guess:

```
run("Synchronize Windows", "select=&Image1 Cursor Scaling z-Slices");
```

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the Synchronize Windows command is not macro recordable. You can see this by [inspecting the source code](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.50g/src/main/java/ij/plugin/frame/SyncWindows.java):

- It does not use `GenericDialog`
- It does not pass any information to the `Recorder`
- It does not provide any `public static` methods for use with `call`

So as far as I can tell, there is really no way to do what you want from a macro.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the link. I actually did check the code before but being a novice I did not have the knowledge to reach any conclusion.

Comment: You could, however, send a message to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.net/Mailing_Lists) requesting this feature, if you really need it.